# android listview's in viewpager register for context menu

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a view pager with 8 tabs / fragments. 
All fragments has a listview with similar content, only sorted differently.
Each listview has an OnItemClicklistener and is also registered for a context menu.
If I select the last tab, no 8, and do a long press to get the context menu. Then I get the item from the list in tab 7.

I register the fragments listview in onCreateView

```
    registerForContextMenu(mListView);
```

And to get the menu item pressed I use the following:

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
int index = info.position;
Log.d("editing for list", "" + mFoodType.ordinal());
if (mContent.get(index).getType() == 0) {
    ...
} else if (mContent.get(index).getType() == 1) {
    ...
}
```

where mContent is a private list in the fragment.

Any idea why I get the item from the wrong fragment?

Comment: have you tried if(index==0){}else if(index==1){}

Comment: @EagleEye thanks, but I'm not sure how it would help to check position in the list with an if statement. I need to know why INDEX has a value from the wrong fragment.